# How to make S3FS use IMDS v2 when mounting s3 buckets from EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

We are unable to mount a S3 bucket on an AWS EC2 instance that requires IMDS v2 (IMDS v1 works fine, though!). We're using s3fs-fuse v1.90 which is supposed to support IMDS v2 (on Ubuntu 18.04).

This is how we've been trying to mount our S3 bucket:

```
sudo s3fs <bucket> <mount-point> -o iam_role=auto,url=https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com,endpoint=eu-central-1,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,mp_umask=007,use_cache=/tmp/s3foldercache,dbglevel=debug -f
```

However, we receive this error message:

```
2021-09-02T12:40:53.157Z [INF]       curl.cpp:LoadIAMRoleFromMetaData(2919): Get IAM Role name
2021-09-02T12:40:53.157Z [DBG] curl_handlerpool.cpp:GetHandler(81): Get handler from pool: rest = 31
2021-09-02T12:40:53.158Z [DBG] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2283): connecting to URL http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
2021-09-02T12:40:53.159Z [ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2394): HTTP response code 401, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>401 - Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 - Unauthorized</h1>
 </body>
</html>

2021-09-02T12:40:53.160Z [CRT] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3395): could not load IAM role name from meta data.
2021-09-02T12:40:53.160Z [ERR] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_exit_fuseloop(3372): Exiting FUSE event loop due to errors
```

Again, when we allow IMDS v1 on our EC2 instance, the mount command works fine.

How do we make sure s3fs will use IMDS v2?

EDIT:
Many thanks to @Noah for contributing a fix for this to s3fs. I've pulled the latest commit but am seeing a new error message now. Apparently IMDSv2 token retrieval fails, regardless of whether I apply `iam_role=auto` or `iam_role=some_profile` (removing `-f` wouldn't change anything either):

```
2021-09-06T05:43:58.857Z [INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3382): init v1.90(commit:9d1552a) with OpenSSL
2021-09-06T05:43:58.857Z [INF]       curl.cpp:LoadIAMRoleFromMetaData(3181): Get IAM Role name
2021-09-06T05:43:58.857Z [DBG] curl_handlerpool.cpp:GetHandler(81): Get handler from pool: rest = 31
2021-09-06T05:43:58.857Z [DBG] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2509): connecting to URL http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token
2021-09-06T05:43:58.889Z [ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2622): HTTP response code 417, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>417 - Expectation Failed</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>417 - Expectation Failed</h1>
 </body>
</html>
2021-09-06T05:43:58.890Z [ERR] curl.cpp:LoadIAMRoleFromMetaData(3212): AWS IMDSv2 token retrieval failed: -5
2021-09-06T05:43:58.890Z [DBG] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2509): connecting to URL http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
2021-09-06T05:43:58.892Z [ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2622): HTTP response code 401, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>401 - Unauthorized</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>401 - Unauthorized</h1>
 </body>
</html>
2021-09-06T05:43:58.892Z [CRT] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3395): could not load IAM role name from meta data.
2021-09-06T05:43:58.892Z [ERR] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_exit_fuseloop(3372): Exiting FUSE event loop due to errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you specify the IAM role explicitly?

It looks like there may be an issue with retrieval of the IAM role information (needed with `iam_role=auto`) when tokens are required.

Additionally, when testing this, I had issues with when the `-f` option is used, so also try removing that.

Below are logs that show the proper token retrieval when mounting a bucket with the following command. Bucket access via the mount point works as expected.

`$ sudo s3fs <REDACTED>  /mnt -o iam_role=s3fs-testing,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,mp_umask=007,use_cache=/tmp/s3foldercache,dbglevel=debug`

```
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: init v1.89(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: check services.
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: IAM Access Token refreshing...
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]:       [IAM role=s3fs-testing]
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: curl_handlerpool.cpp:GetHandler(81): Get handler from pool: rest = 31
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2254): connecting to URL http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]:       HTTP response code 200
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]:       Setting AWS IMDSv2 API token to <REDACTED>
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2254): connecting to URL http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3fs-testing
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]:       HTTP response code 200
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]:       IAM credential response = "{
                                          "Code" : "Success",
                                          "LastUpdated" : "2021-09-02T15:36:20Z",
                                          "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
                                          "AccessKeyId" : "REDACTED",
                                          "SecretAccessKey" : "REDACTED",
                                          "Token" : "REDACTED",
                                          "Expiration" : "2021-09-02T22:10:48Z"
                                        }"
Sep 02 16:06:46 ip-10-0-0-77 s3fs[600]: IAM Access Token refreshed
```

Comment: This should be fixed permanently upstream as of https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/pull/1760

Comment: Thank you @Noah for even committing a fix for this to s3fs. I've pulled your changes but am seeing a new error message indicating that token retrieval fails. I updated my original post with the latest error message.

Comment: I have no idea what could be triggering the "417 - Expectation Failed" response from IMDS.


What instance type are you using?


If you use curl, do you get a token?


`$ curl -v -X PUT -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token ; echo`

Comment: I do receive a valid token when running that curl command. I believe this is another issue apart from the one I originally posted here, so I'll close this one assuming that your submission to s3fs has fixed the ```iam_role=auto``` problem (even though I haven't been able to validate it, yet).  
I opened a new topic for the 417 error msg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104247/s3fs-how-to-mount-s3-buckets-on-aws-ec2-instances-behind-proxy-using-imds-v2

Comment: It is a bug in s3fs. See my answer to your new post.

Comment: I could finally validate that ```iam_role=auto``` now also works for IMDS v2 !